# How to resolve reference with subquery in ATHENA

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

i have this query in athena which refer to a struct

```
select monitoredobject.id
from lv1_trip
```

now, i want to do something like this

```
select monitoredobject.id
from 
(select monitoredobject.id as 'user' from
lv1_trip) mytable
```

but i can't do this because of ambiguity of reference.
How can i solve it?

Comment: In your subquery you alias monitoredobject.id as 'user'.  So change your outer select to `select user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity here, the subquery result does not have `monitoredobject` column so you can't select it, you need to select the new column - `user`:

```sql
select "user"
from 
  (select monitoredobject.id as "user" 
  from lv1_trip) mytable
```